# aws sdk Multipart Upload to s3 with node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to upload large files to a s3 bucket using the node.js `aws-sdk`.

the `V2` method `upload` integrally uploads the files in a **multipart upload**.

I want to use the new V3 aws-sdk. What is the way to upload large files in the new version? The method `PutObjectCommand` doesn't seem to be doing it.

I've seen there are methods such as `CreateMultiPartUpload` but I can't seem to find a full working example using them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

As of 2021, I would suggest using the [lib-storage](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/lib/lib-storage/README.md) package, which abstracts a lot of the implementation details.

Sample code:

```
import { Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";
import { S3Client, S3 } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const target = { Bucket, Key, Body };
try {
  const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
    client: new S3({}) || new S3Client({}),
    tags: [...], // optional tags
    queueSize: 4, // optional concurrency configuration
    partSize: 5MB, // optional size of each part
    leavePartsOnError: false, // optional manually handle dropped parts
    params: target,
  });

  parallelUploads3.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress) => {
    console.log(progress);
  });

  await parallelUploads3.done();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/lib/lib-storage/README.md

Comment: For some reason, my app's memory only increase with this approach. I couldn't find how to use the v3 in a good and performatic way.

Comment: I've had a good experience using this approach so far. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RhadamezGindriHercilio have to agree with you here, I'm seeing memory increase over time when bulk uploading. Did you find an alternative solution by chance?

Comment: @JordanLewallen, actually yes, but I end up with another solution that did the same thing much better, I can show you.

Comment: @RhadamezGindriHercilio would LOVE to see a gist or link for a solution. Been struggling to fix this. Thank you!!

Comment: The doc says somewhere that it will buffer queuesize * partsize in memory, so that may be why you're seeing memory usage growing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I came up with, to upload a Buffer as a multipart upload, using aws-sdk v3 for nodejs and TypeScript.

Error handling still needs some work (you might want to abort/retry in case of an error), but it should be a good starting point... I have tested this with XML files up to 15MB, and so far so good. No guarantees, though! ;)

```
import {
  CompleteMultipartUploadCommand,
  CompleteMultipartUploadCommandInput,
  CreateMultipartUploadCommand,
  CreateMultipartUploadCommandInput,
  S3Client,
  UploadPartCommand,
  UploadPartCommandInput
} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'

const client = new S3Client({ region: 'us-west-2' })

export const uploadMultiPartObject = async (file: Buffer, createParams: CreateMultipartUploadCommandInput): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const createUploadResponse = await client.send(
      new CreateMultipartUploadCommand(createParams)
    )
    const { Bucket, Key } = createParams
    const { UploadId } = createUploadResponse
    console.log('Upload initiated. Upload ID: ', UploadId)

    // 5MB is the minimum part size
    // Last part can be any size (no min.)
    // Single part is treated as last part (no min.)
    const partSize = (1024 * 1024) * 5 // 5MB
    const fileSize = file.length
    const numParts = Math.ceil(fileSize / partSize)

    const uploadedParts = []
    let remainingBytes = fileSize

    for (let i = 1; i <= numParts; i ++) {
      let startOfPart = fileSize - remainingBytes
      let endOfPart = Math.min(partSize, startOfPart + remainingBytes)

      if (i > 1) {
        endOfPart = startOfPart + Math.min(partSize, remainingBytes)
        startOfPart += 1
      }

      const uploadParams: UploadPartCommandInput = {
        // add 1 to endOfPart due to slice end being non-inclusive
        Body: file.slice(startOfPart, endOfPart + 1),
        Bucket,
        Key,
        UploadId,
        PartNumber: i
      }
      const uploadPartResponse = await client.send(new UploadPartCommand(uploadParams))
      console.log(`Part #${i} uploaded. ETag: `, uploadPartResponse.ETag)

      remainingBytes -= Math.min(partSize, remainingBytes)

      // For each part upload, you must record the part number and the ETag value.
      // You must include these values in the subsequent request to complete the multipart upload.
      // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CompleteMultipartUpload.html
      uploadedParts.push({ PartNumber: i, ETag: uploadPartResponse.ETag })
    }

    const completeParams: CompleteMultipartUploadCommandInput = {
      Bucket,
      Key,
      UploadId,
      MultipartUpload: {
        Parts: uploadedParts
      }
    }
    console.log('Completing upload...')
    const completeData = await client.send(new CompleteMultipartUploadCommand(completeParams))
    console.log('Upload complete: ', completeData.Key, '\n---')
  } catch(e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same MalformedXML error. Also, when I run your code I still get the same ETag for each part

Comment: Actually, all ETags are identical apart from the first and last one.

Comment: I get Etag undefined...which occurs the "The XML you provided was not well-formatted..." error on CompleteMultipartUploadCommand. other than that it seems working nicely.

Comment: This was the issue
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3177#issuecomment-1062967707

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fully working code with AWS SDK v3

```
import { Upload } from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";
import { S3Client, S3 } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';

const inputStream = createReadStream('clamav_db.zip');
const Bucket = process.env.DB_BUCKET
const Key = process.env.FILE_NAME
const Body = inputStream

const target = { Bucket, Key, Body};
try {
  const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
    client: new S3Client({
      region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
      credentials: { accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY }
    }),
    queueSize: 4, // optional concurrency configuration
    partSize: 5242880, // optional size of each part
    leavePartsOnError: false, // optional manually handle dropped parts
    params: target,
  });

  parallelUploads3.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress) => {
    console.log(progress);
  });

  await parallelUploads3.done();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```