# AWS Javascript SDK to copy S3 objects more than 5 GB

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-sdk

I need to copy S3 objects which is more than 5 GB from one S3 bucket to another. I have successfully done it using boto3 but facing issue while doing it in JS.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source,targetBucket,new_key)
```

The above code is working correctly and it copies object >5GB.

Now I need to implement same in JS.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');    
const s3 = new AWS.S3();    
await s3.copyObject({Bucket,CopySource,Key})
```

I understand that the above code will only copy objects not  more than 5GB and we will have to utilize multipart upload like done in boto3.

I even went through the aws documentation but could'nt find a way to do so in JS.

Comment: Did you look at the JavaScript code provided in the official documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpu-upload-object.html or perhaps the first search result for "NodeJS S3 MultiPart Upload" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66656565/aws-sdk-multipart-upload-to-s3-with-node-js